# "Incompatible types in initialisation" error makes no sense

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been a Java programmer for years but only iPhone/Obj-c for a few months. Every time I think I'm comfortable with the language something weird happens. Why does the following generate a "Incompatible types in initialisation" compile error? It seems so straight forward. 'double' is a primitive right?!?

```
-(void) testCalling{
   double myDoub = [self functionReturningDouble:3.0];
}


-(double) functionReturningDouble:(double) input{
   return 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Is the second method declared previously? Otherwise the return-type is assumed to be `id`.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to declare private/internal methods in a class extension at the top of your implementation (`.m`) file. That practice removes position dependency on the implementation and use of private/internal methods. (Apple Docs: http://devworld.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to swap the method declarations. It may be a scope problem as Georg notices:

```
-(double) functionReturningDouble:(double) input{
    return 1.0;
}

-(void) testCalling{
    double myDoub = [self functionReturningDouble:3.0];
}
```

In Objective-C (and this is valid for C), a method does "exists" only if it has been defined or declared before.

Comment: Rather, a methods signatures is only known in those cases :)

Comment: Thankyou! Can't believe it took this long to discover this.

Comment: Just another point.. out of interest why does the order not seem to matter with a int method but only with double?

Comment: This is because the default return type for an undefined function is "int".